# What are the differences between GCC gnu89, Visual Studio C (2008), and GCC c89?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, gcc

I'm trying to get a handle on different C platforms to create the most portable code possible.  Is there a resource which enumerates the differences between these implementations of the C89 standard?

Comment: I think all these platforms support full C89 standard. (Correct me if I'm wrong) However, portability is more than that, for instance, `sizoef(int)` may be `2` or `4` on different machines, and that's something the standard doesn't specify.

Comment: "Most portable" would seem to refer to the goal of maximizing the number of platforms that would correctly run your programs. But you only specified two. Is the goal here only to run on both recent GCC and VS? If so, don't worry, because both should be fully compliant with C89 (aka C90). Just look for C90 resources.

Comment: BTW, `gnu89` refers to the language containing GCC specific extensions, the entire purpose of which was to trade-off portability for convenience. So that shouldn't be a consideration unless you're really limiting yourself and you're sure VS emulation of GCC is up to snuff.

Comment: gnu89 is the default gcc compiler.  The code I have does not compile with c89, but compiles with VS2008 and gnu89.  I need to know where these two compilers are "coloring outside the lines".

Comment: Since you said "it does not compile with c89", isn't this "where" question answered by the location/nature of the error messages?

Comment: @chill, one difference is not all differences.